# Specifying abstract type members

Tags: scala

Is there a way to access an abstract type member?

For example, how would I define a type for `A` of `Foo` and `Bar`?

```scala
trait Foo {
    type A
}

trait Bar {
    type A
}

case class Qux() extends Foo with Bar {
    type Foo#A = String
    type Bar#A = Int
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class `Qux` only has to (and can only) provide a single definition of type `A` to satisfy the abstract requirements of `Foo` and `Bar`,

```
case class Qux() extends Foo with Bar {
  type A = Int
}
```

If one or both of the definitions in `Foo` and `Bar` are concrete or bounded, then the definition in `Qux` must satisfy them both, for example,

```
trait Foo {
  type A <: AnyRef
}

trait Bar {
  type A <: String
}

case class Qux() extends Foo with Bar {
  type A = String // Bounded by both AnyRef and String
}
```

Because the intersection of `Int` and `String` is empty, it's unlikely that definitions of `Foo` and `Bar` of quite the form in your question are what you're looking for, however the following is possible,

```
trait Foo {
  type A <: Int
}

trait Bar {
  type A <: String
}

case class Qux() extends Foo with Bar {
  type A = Int with String // Uninhabited type
}
```